# (SHA?) hashes on receipts

Tags: regulations, latvia

After my holiday to Latvia, I was doing my administration and I noticed that almost all receipts had cryptographic hashes on the bottom. One receipt defined them as SHA1. Adding hashes to receipts is something that I'm not familiar with. Some googeling around learns me that this is normal with cryptocurrencies, but these payments were all by card (whether by Apple Pay or by inserting the card into the terminal).

Two example receipts:

[image: Example receipt]

[image: Example receipt 2]
*(Redacted the last piece of the hash because I don't know what value is stored in it...)*

---

My question is: **What is the meaning of these hashes, and what is stored in it?**

I wonder why this is done, since I, as a customer, am probably not able to recalculate this exact hash from the layout of the receipt. Is this a checksum that the bank can use to verify the receipt?

---

Notes:

- *Yes, I know SHA1 isn't secure, and **imo** shouldn't be used anywhere anymore because of [the fact that a collision can be created](https://shattered.io/) these days; and that there are better alternatives. This makes me wonder even more what it's purpose is.*
- *I chose to post my question here because this **isn't a technical question as to how a SHA1 hash as a (presumably) checksum works**. I know how to calculate a hash. The question relates to why these values are added to receipts, and what their purpose and content is. I won't find an answer to this on SO.*
- *This isn't normal in my country, The Netherlands. I have never seen this, and going back in my administration shows no signs of hashes on my (Dutch) receipts.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see how this is a travel question.

Comment: @Chris H Well, where else would you expect this type of question? I would argue that this is a travel question, since I suspect this has to do with foreign regulations (hence the tag).

Comment: I don't know of an SE website where I would consider this to be on topic (I'd have suggested it if I did know one). But "it's off-topic everywhere else" doesn't make it on-topic here, and in my opinion (while I agree that it's quite interesting) this question isn't on-topic here. If others disagree with me I'll be outvoted in the review and the question will remain open.

Comment: I don’t think it fits on-topic either https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MagicLegend I'd suggest asking this on one of the computing StackExchange sites. While this question includes travel (ie a receipt from a foreign country), the question itself is about the hash, which would be much more easily answered elsewhere

Comment: They're just saying that their POS/POI terminals are not PCI-compliant. SHA hashes are used to digitally sign POS transactions, but the use of SHA-1 should have stopped in 2017 I believe. May be ask on [security.se]

Comment: The only thing stored in the hash is the hash itself. Perhaps you instead meant to ask what information was used to compute it?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I'll repost this question on the Information Security SE, since I agree with @mustaccio that it might have more relevance there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sure, that is technically indeed what happens. But, since I was trying to keep the question open for a broader audience I formulated it like this to make it clearer for the less-tech savvy under us.

Comment: After a bit of searching around after to @mustaccio 's comment about PCI-compliance, I found the [following page](https://blog.pcisecuritystandards.org/how-the-sha-1-collision-impacts-security-of-payments) that talks about the exact issue I mentioned, the possible collisions in SHA-1. A bit of clicking further, and reading some [specification](http://bit.ly/pci-v4) [documents](http://bit.ly/faq-sha1) I have to conclude that the values are indeed some form of checksum, probably about the pin terminal used. Again, thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: I went over to [security.se] but I couldn't find the reposted question?

Comment: Correct @MichaelHampton. I never reposted the question, since I also didn't found it fit for there. However, I accidentally knew people in the SHA-compliance industry; and I showed them this post. They agreed that it was probably some checksum. And that is was SHA-1 was something they shrugged at; saying "Well, it has to be calculated really quickly on really sh*tty hardware". For me this answered the question well enough.